# What does rsync's "lq%n%Lrq" default output format mean?

Tags: logging, rsync

Regarding [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync), it is possible to define the verbose output format of rsync by the `--out-format` flag:

> --out-format=FORMAT     output updates using the specified FORMAT

> --out-format=FORMAT This allows you to specify exactly what the rsync client outputs to the user on a per-update basis. The format is a text
> string containing embedded single-character escape sequences prefixed
> with a percent (%) character. A default format of lq%n%Lrq is assumed
> if -v is specified (which reports the name of the file and, if the
> item is a link, where it points). For a full list of the possible
> escape characters, see the lqlog formatrq setting in the rsyncd.conf
> manpage. Specifying the --out-format option will mention each file,
> dir, etc. that gets updated in a significant way (a transferred file,
> a recreated symlink/device, or a touched directory). In addition, if
> the itemize-changes escape (%i) is included in the string (e.g. if the
> --itemize-changes option was used), the logging of names increases to mention any item that is changed in any way (as long as the receiving
> side is at least 2.6.4). See the --itemize-changes option for a
> description of the output of lq%irq.

This means `lq%n%Lrq` is the default.

In addition it says `lq%irq` is explained in the `--itemize-changes` part:

> The lq%irq escape has a cryptic output that is 11 letters long. The
> general format is like the string YXcstpoguax, where Y is replaced by
> the type of update being done, X is replaced by the file-type, and the
> other letters represent attributes that may be output if they are
> being modified.

Ok, now I'm as clever as before ^^

What means `lq`? And what means `%irq` or `YXcstpoguax`?

[In this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/466107/44086) someone explains %t, %f and %b and I found those "variables" [in the rsyncd.conf documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf#:%7E:text=log%20format), but while there is an example which contains `lq` and `rq`, it does not explain its meaning:

> The default log format is lq%o %h [%a] %m (%u) %f %lrq, and a lq%t
> [%p] rq

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say that site's manpage-to-html converter is barfing and generating `lq` and `rq` instead of left- and right-quote characters.  E.g., `lq%irq` should probably just be `"%i"` or something.  (Thus rendering `lq%n%Lrq` into `"%n%L"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lq` is supposed to be a left quote, and `rq` is supposed to be a right quote.

From Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS:

> --out-format=FORMAT
>
> This allows you to specify exactly what the rsync client outputs to the user  on  a  per-update  basis. The  format is a text string containing embedded single-character escape sequences prefixed with a percent (%) character.   A default format of "%n%L" is assumed if either --info=name or  -v  is  specified (this  tells  you  just  the name of the file and, if the item is a link, where it points).  For a full list of the possible escape characters, see the "log format" setting in the rsyncd.conf manpage.
>
> Specifying the --out-format option implies the --info=name option, which will mention each  file,  dir, etc.  that  gets  updated  in  a  significant way (a transferred file, a recreated symlink/device, or a touched directory).  In addition, if the itemize-changes escape (%i) is included in the string (e.g. if the  --itemize-changes  option  was  used),  the logging of names increases to mention any item that is changed in any way (as long as the receiving side is at least 2.6.4).  See the --itemize-changes option for a description of the output of "%i".
>
> Rsync will output the out-format string prior to a file’s transfer unless one of the transfer-statistic escapes is requested, in which case the logging is done at the end of the file’s transfer.   When  this late logging is in effect and --progress is also specified, rsync will also output the name of the file being transferred prior to its progress information (followed, of course, by the out-format output).

Comment: Ok, that's embarrassing, but thank you for the enlightening.